# Carrierwave store images locally not on s3 at heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I am using carrier wave to upload images and display them in a photo-gallery. Carrier wave store files at `public/uploads`. But these images are not getting displayed at heroku. I found that heroku is read only and we should store files at s3.

Is there any other alternatives than s3?If yes, can you please share here?

Comment: you can probably use a different file store which has some sort of API for which you can create a custom class.  You can also look at the wiki https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki and search for alternative storage options.

Answer (score 6):

Heroku is only `read only` if you're on the `bamboo` stack (old). For `cedar`, they use a [`ephemeral writeable filesystem`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem), which means that whilst you can upload, it gets wiped with every deploy

S3 is not your only option; it's just Amazon's storage system. You've got [**dropbox**](https://github.com/janko-m/paperclip-dropbox), [**Azure**](https://github.com/gmontard/paperclip-azure-storage),  [**RackSpace**](https://gist.github.com/bigs/4956380) & a bunch of others which provide similar functionality

---

Your question should really be **`which storage solution is right for my app?`**

The main issue is the location of your files -- they need to be close in proximity to your app, to reduce latency. We've had a problem recently hosting `S3` files through a `Rackspace` app - because S3 is not in RackSpace's datacenter, the latency was high

Because [Heroku is built on Amazon's AWS cloud](http://www.quora.com/Scalability/How-does-Heroku-work), meaning serving assets from S3 the most efficient & logical method to provide your assets