# Carrierwave and Heroku does not work with seeding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, carrierwave, seeding

I have configured a carrierwave uploader this way:

```
class PortraitUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

    # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
    include CarrierWave::RMagick
    # include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

    # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
    storage :file
    # storage :fog

    # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
    # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
    def store_dir
        "#{Rails.root}/public/images/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
    end

    def cache_dir
        "#{Rails.root}/tmp/uploads"
    end
end
```

And my seeds are like so:

```
Portrait.create({
    main: true,
    image: open('http://some-image-out-there.jpg'),
    customer: @hatakeda
})
```

In development works 100%.

When uploading my app to Heroku, I can still use the uploader to manually set images, either by uploading or by sending the url

However thee seed creates image urls that does not display an image - 404 error.

How can I make Carrierwave, Heroku and my seedings work together happily?

Comment: "does not work" - what does it mean?

Comment: Are you trying to store images on heroku? Short answer: you can't. If uploading worked, those files will get wiped during your next deploy or when workers restart for any reason. Have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23102185/carrierwave-store-images-locally-not-on-s3-at-heroku

Comment: @basia I see. That's too bad. Thanks for the info - make it answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to store images on heroku? Short answer: you can't, as Heroku is read-only (`ephemeral writeable filesystem`). If uploading worked, those files will get wiped during your next deploy or when workers restart for any reason. Have a look [Carrierwave store images locally not on s3 at heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23102185/carrierwave-store-images-locally-not-on-s3-at-heroku).